# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. configuration Build failed with an exception

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-android-0.72.4-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.4) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download react-android-0.72.4-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.4)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.72.4/react-android-0.72.4-debug.aar'.
> > Tag mismatch!
> Failed to transform hermes-android-0.72.4-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.72.4) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download hermes-android-0.72.4-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.72.4)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/hermes-android/0.72.4/hermes-android-0.72.4-debug.aar'.
> > Tag mismatch!

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

How to remove the problem

Comment: Show the code where the error occurred